# Use Custom Module collection in other custom Module magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.2.2, magento2.3.5

I want collection of one module in other module. I am doing it like

```
use Test\CompanyAddresses\Model\CompanyAddressFactory;

class ReformatTelephoneField implements DataPatchInterface
{
    protected $companyAddressFactory;

    /**
     * @param CompanyAddressFactory $companyAddressFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CompanyAddressFactory $companyAddressFactory
    ) {
        $this->companyAddressFactory = $companyAddressFactory;
    }

public function apply()
    {
        $companyAddressCollection = $this->companyAddressFactory->create()->getCollection();
    }
}
```

I have provided basic code logic that how I am getting collection but on setup:upgrade I am getting issue like Model collection resource name is not defined. Don't know what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit module sequence

`etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Module1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Test_Module2_WITH_COLLECTION"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```